# Append image file type check to include PDF?

Tags: javascript

I've been using this simple check for image file type in a Javascript Image Uploader:

```
/* Is the file an image? */
if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;
```

It's working fine, but would also like to include PDF files. Can this statement be appended to include PDF file types?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (!file || !file.type.match(/image\/.*|application\/pdf/)) return;
```

Use this for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_application